# Copying previous line for NA line based on column

Tags: r

I have 2 data sets that look the same:

```
                    High    Low   Open  Close Volume
2013-01-02 02:01:00 7760.0 7740.0 7744.5 7752.5   1747 
2013-01-02 02:02:00 7755.0 7745.5 7753.0 7752.0    456
2013-01-02 02:03:00 7773.5 7752.5 7752.5 7772.5    448
2013-01-02 02:04:00 7792.0 7772.5 7772.5 7791.0    624 
2013-01-02 02:05:00 7799.0 7789.0 7791.0 7793.0    714 
2013-01-02 02:06:00 7793.5 7789.5 7793.0 7789.5    323
```

SYM1 holds 165,990 lines but SYM2 holds 158,900 lines.

When used `SYM1and2 <- merge(SYM1, SYM2, all=TRUE)` I managed to merge the 2 df into 1 but I have missing datapoints as in this example:

```
2013-01-02 13:17:00 7769.0  7768.5  7768.5  7768.5  4   2692    2692    2692    2692    84 678  
2013-01-02 13:18:00 7769.0  7769.0  7769.0  7769.0  3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 679  
2013-01-02 13:19:00 7769.5  7769.0  7769.0  7769.5  4   2693    2692    2693    2692    138 680 
2013-01-02 13:20:00 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  2692    2692    2692    2692    4 681   
2013-01-02 13:21:00 7770.0  7769.0  7769.0  7770.0  17  2694    2693    2693    2694    124
```

How do I copy the previos line in that specific df into the NA line so there will be a continues in the data and no NA?

Comment: `zoo::na.locf` does the operation which you are describing. example: `dat <- mtcars; dat[2:32, ] <- NA; zoo::na.locf(dat)`

Comment: sorry @rawr i didn't understand how to run the exaple you provided. could you pls be kind and elaborate?

Comment: Do you know how to install packages? Just do `install.packages("zoo");
library(zoo);
SYM1and2 <- na.locf(SYM1and2)`